# Objective-C 10.10 NSApplication delegate cannot call method defined in delegate class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates, osx-yosemite

tldr, the simple question is: in OS X 10.10 I cannot call methods defined in a delegate class.

Some information as below:

I have a sample Cocoa project, which has a delegate class, and its method defined as below:

```
@interface SPVAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
- (void)doSomething;
end
```

If I compile the project with 10.9 SDK, I can call this method doSomething in other part of the program like this:

```
[[NSApp delegate] doSomething];
```

But, with 10.10 SDK, I would get this error when compiling the project:

```
No known instance method for selector 'doSomething'
```

Why this method is not found if I use 10.10 SDK? Is there anything changed in the API here?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think I found a solution, I have to convert the type of [NSApp delegate] explicitly to the delegate class in order to call the method, which is:

```
[(SPVAppDelegate *)[NSApp delegate] doSomething];
```

In 10.10, delegate is defined as:

```
@property (assign) id<NSApplicationDelegate> delegate;
```

In 10.9, it was like:

```
- (id <NSApplicationDelegate>)delegate;
```

So delegate becomes a real property in 10.10, but the return type is still id. I am still not sure why this change could cause this issue.

Comment: The same issue happened on 10.9 with Xcode 6.1. I fixed the problem by explicit choosing the "Base SDK" as OSX 10.9 at build settings.